# Why is this contract using too much gas? (infinite)

Tags: solidity

I've been playing around with this contract for the past couple of hours, the logic seems ok from my side (please correct me if I am mistaken), but I don't understand why in the analysis I am getting the error `Fallback function of contract Lottery requires too much gas (infinite). If the fallback function requires more than 2300 gas, the contract cannot receive Ether.`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Lottery {
  address private owner;

  address[] public players;
  uint private lastCount;

  address[] public winners;
  uint[] public prizes;

  uint private min = 1 ether;
  uint private fee = 0.1 ether;

  function Lottery() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function enter() public payable {
    address player = msg.sender;
    require(player != owner);
    require(msg.value >= min);
    players.push(player);
    owner.transfer(fee);
  }

  function () public payable {
    enter();
  }

  function getPlayersCount() public view returns (uint) {
    return players.length - lastCount;
  }

  function pick(uint index) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    require(getPlayersCount() > 0);
    address winner = players[lastCount + index];
    require(winner != address(0));
    winners.push(winner);
    prizes.push(this.balance);
    lastCount = players.length;
    winner.transfer(this.balance);
  }

  function getWinnersCount() public view returns (uint) {
    return winners.length;
  }

  function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]) {
    return players;
  }

  function getWinners() public view returns (address[], uint[]) {
    return (winners, prizes);
  }
}
```

At first I thought that the issue was caused by `players = new address[](0);` so I switched to a safer approach (using a `lastCount` pointer instead of clearing the array), but still.

I also tried `players[players.length++] = player;` which strangely keeps the analysis engine happy, but results a broken functionality.

Anybody can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that any call to a dynamic array's `push(...)` method triggers the infinite gas warning. It's safe to ignore.

That said, as a rule, I advise against using the anonymous fallback function when you can avoid it. See my reasoning here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/16/be-careful-when-using-the-solidity-fallback-function/.

As an aside, why would anyone participate in a lottery where the owner picks the winner? Ethereum enables *trustless* apps, but this seems to require trusting a central authority to determine the outcome.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to ignore, I am getting a Max Transaction Fee of 0.549199 ETH 466.57 USD on MetaMask on the Ropsten network. I will check your post about the fallback function, I just started diving deep into all of this, today we learn how to build a simple dummy application, tomorrow we build something more sophisticated, although one could argue that in this case the owner could be a machine too. The current available methods to generate a random integer in Solidity are too deterministic in my opinion, that's why I skipped its implantation here.

Comment: What tool is showing you that max transaction fee? What are the values for the gas price and gas limit? Did you choose either of those values or were they chosen for you by the tool you're using?

Comment: Sorry; I just saw that you're using MetaMask, so ignore my question about which tool. :-)

Comment: Also, could you link to the contract on Ropsten?

Comment: Sure, here is the contract address 0xB3396702ae1d658Ac7A90493aAC112DDF41bee3F, thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you deployed? I can't get Etherscan to verify the code.

Comment: In a quick test of the code in the question in Remix with the JavaScript VM, calling `enter()` consumed 70670 gas.

Comment: The deployed version has different min and fee values that'a why. It does run on Remix and even on ganache but the warnings are still thrown in the test net, I take it you are not spotting anything sketchy within the code?

Comment: Try it on Remix with the injected web3 from MetaMask, you should see the warning

Comment: Can you verify the actual source code on Etherscan? (Or share it here?) Testing against a contract I can't read the source code for makes for difficult debugging. :-)

Comment: I did try Remix with MetaMask using the address you provided, and calling `enter()` with a value of 1 ether gives a max transaction fee of 0.000073 eth ($0.06 USD). It's showing a gas limit of 73213 and a gas price of 1 gwei. (Unless I missed it, you never shared your numbers, but those are mine for comparison so you can figure out which one is out of whack.)

Comment: I uninstalled MetaMask and reinstalled it again, and now it works for some reason, so the logic was indeed correct from the start. Does MetaMask put large amounts of gas as input if it estimated the contract to throw some how?

Comment: This answers the original question in the title, and also the issue mentioned is no longer present.